# Differentiability of non-analytic complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Any complex function that is analytic on an open set is differentiable on that set.

But can a function fail to be analytic on an open set but still be differentiable?

For example, the function $f(z)=z|z|^2$ is not analytic on an open set. Is it differentiable? The Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied only at $z=0$, which isn't an open set.

How do you determine if a complex function is differentiable?

Comment: If you consider your function $f$ as a mapping $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, it is differentiable. If you mean complex differentiability instead of real, then analyticity and differentiability coincide. In fact, any mapping $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ can be interpreted as a mapping $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, and this gives you plenty of examples. A function can even be real analytic from the plane to itself without being complex analytic.

Comment: For your second question: Cauchy-Riemann equations are the most common way to determine complex differentiablity. Of course you can directly use the definition of differentiablity.

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied for $z=0$ - does that mean that f is complex differentiable at $z=0$ or must it be satisfied on an open set too?

Comment: Yeah, sure it is complex differentiable at $z=0$! You can also see that from the limit definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little subtle. Even if a function satsifies Cauchy-Riemann's equations, it's not necessarily $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable. Take for example
$$
f(z) = \begin{cases} \exp(-1/z^4), & z \neq 0 \\ 0 & z = 0 \end{cases}.
$$
As an exercise, you can check that $f$ satsifies C-R everywhere (it's pretty much obvious outside the origin), but $f$ is certainly not an entire function. It isn't even continuous at $z=0$. The problem is that Cauchy-Riemann's equation only care about restrictions of $f$ to vertical and horizontal lines.

However, if you know that $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable and satisfies C-R at a point, then $f$ is also $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable there. Your example has smooth ($C^\infty$) real and imaginary part, and is thus $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable. In other words, for your particular example, checking Cauchy-Riemann's equations is suffcient.

Comment: Well, and by Looman-Menchoff theorem, a continuous complex function is holomorphic in some region if and only if it satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations everywhere.